# find function in c++ <algorithm>

Tags: c++, stl, find

I'm using g++ 7.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

I think I have found a bug:

```
vector<int> a(10,1);
vector<int>::iterator it = find(a.begin()+6,a.begin()+3,8);
if(it != a.end()) cout<<"FOUND"<<endl;
```

Result:

```
FOUND
```

Is it supposed to be not found ? I also found that:

```
it = a.begin()+3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a bug.  It follows the standard definition perfectly:

From [[alg.find]](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.find)

> Let *E* be:
>     — `*i == value` for `find`,
>     ...
>
> *Returns*: The first iterator `i` in the range [`first`, `last`) for which *E* is `true`. Returns `last` if no such iterator is found.

Since there is no iterator `i` in the range [`a.begin()+6`, `a.begin()+3`) for which `*i == 8` holds true, `std::find` returns `a.begin()+3`.

Comment: Is it undefined behavior if `first > last`?

Comment: @Kevin I can't find any precondition that says that.  It's totally possible it's there and I've missed it though.

Comment: so the algorithm in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/ is wrong ? it should be `while(first < last)` instead of `while(first != last)`

Comment: @Duy It returns _the first iterator in the range `[first, last)`.  The iterators for find are _InputI terators_ which can only be compared for equality. Since your range is reversed (where last < first) you have Undefined Behavior.  You're lucky it returns something, rather than crashing.  The MSVC compiler with iterator debugging enabled will report a runtime error of "transposed pointer range".